I have a system with two pumps running, I want to turn one pump on and off from a raspberry pi,if the raspberry fails, I want the second pump to run
I have been trying (for a week) to design a circuit where the first pump is controlled by an NPN transistor and the emitter is connected to the base of the PNP, I have assumed that when the NPN is closed, the PNP is off but either i have the circuit design wrong or the resistance values are not correct but it doesn't work as expected. I have used LEDs in LT SPice to mimic the loads. Any guidance, very gratefully received, I am new to working with transisitors and having a struggle with how the PNP splits the inbound current
I have adjusted the resistor values and inverted the transistors, put the load on the other side of the transistors, all of which didn't work, the current coming out of the base of the PNP is stronger than the current coming from the NPN is what I think is happening but not too sure
